# Cannot replicate CouchDB 2.0.0

Tags: couchdb, database-replication

> Update: I can replicate from my Linux 1.6.0 db to my windows 2.0.0 db
>   - but not the other way around or local on the 2.0.0 windows version.

I am trying to replicate some couchdb databases without much success (locally or remote).  I am using 2.0.0

In Chrome, it just runs forever but the console shows error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Same in Edge/Chrome, with error:

```
SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
(XHR): POST - http://localhost:5984/_replicate
```

I have tried with multiple databases, even after creating a new database with one test document.  I have tried options of 'Create Target' and 'Continuous' but those do not help.

Here is the info from couchdb.log for the last time I tried:

```
[notice] 2016-12-08T23:52:40.310000Z couchdb@localhost <0.4906.274> ebb6bec9c6 starting new replication `9e9dc106fd455677482ba1d594c547c6+create_target` at <0.5136.274> (`http://0.0.0.0:5984/abcdefg/` -> `http://0.0.0.0:5984/red/`)
[notice] 2016-12-08T23:52:40.312000Z couchdb@localhost <0.5136.274> -------- Retrying GET request to http://0.0.0.0:5984/abcdefg/ in 0.25 seconds due to error {conn_failed,{error,eaddrnotavail}}
[notice] 2016-12-08T23:52:40.571000Z couchdb@localhost <0.5136.274> -------- Retrying GET request to http://0.0.0.0:5984/abcdefg/ in 0.5 seconds due to error {conn_failed,{error,eaddrnotavail}}
[notice] 2016-12-08T23:52:41.087000Z couchdb@localhost <0.5136.274> -------- Retrying GET request to http://0.0.0.0:5984/abcdefg/ in 1.0 seconds due to error {conn_failed,{error,eaddrnotavail}}
[notice] 2016-12-08T23:52:42.104000Z couchdb@localhost <0.5136.274> -------- Retrying GET request to http://0.0.0.0:5984/abcdefg/ in 2.0 seconds due to error {conn_failed,{error,eaddrnotavail}}
```

I have tried changing the IP to the IP of the machine (instead of all 0's to where it binds to all addy's)

Any ideas of what I could try?

Comment: Your CouchDB 2.0 is all setup (single node vs cluster) ?

Comment: Actually it was not.  I did make that change (single node), restarted the service, no luck, changed ip back to 0.0.0.0, restarted service, no luck, same error as above in couchdb.log but no error in console this time.  My linux 1.6 works fine (and didnt have the additional step) - thanks for pointing that out, i think i am closer :-)